# Bug with tf.image.convert_image_dtype? Values not scaling

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using Tensorflow's image.convert_image_dtype
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype
to convert a png of dtype uint16 to float32.

Using Tensorflow 1.12.0.

According to the documentation:
*Images that are represented using floating point values are expected to have values in the range [0,1). Image data stored in integer data types are expected to have values in the range [0,MAX], where MAX is the largest positive representable number for the data type.
**This op converts between data types, scaling the values appropriately before casting**.*

This should put my values in [0,1) for float conversion, but when evaluating the new float32 tensor, my white pixels are near 65535 - the max for uint16. It appears no scaling of any sort up or down occured.

Was I performing the operation wrong? Should I just divide the elements by 65535 to get the properly formatted float tensor?

Comment: Could you please add the code to your question ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.
Use of resize before type conversion changes the tensor type so Tensorflow won't do the scaling properly.

I was using:

```
#CAUSES SCALING ISSUE
file1 = tf.read_file("my_filename_here.png")
img = tf.image.decode_png(file1, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint16)
sizedImage = tf.image.resize_images(img, shape, shape)
finalimg = tf.convert_image_dtype(sizedImage, tf.float32)
```

This resulted in no scaling. Fixed by doing the conversion directly after decoding.

```
#CORRECT
file1 = tf.read_file("my_filename_here.png")
img = tf.image.decode_png(file1, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint16)
img = tf.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
finalImage = tf.image.resize_images(img, shape, shape)
```

I had thought that I could make it more efficient by downscaling before converting, but this breaks it. In summary: **Do convert_image_dtype directly after decoding.**

Answer (score 0):

Specify the dtype when decoding the image, or else tensorflow autograph specifies the dtype for you, which causes problems with resize_ functions.

So, in your case the dtype specification would be

```
img = tf.image.decode_png(file1, channels=1, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Also, resize does return an image with dtype float32, so it must be cast again to uint after using resize, rather than converted, if it was already converted before. So, better yet, the proper order is decode, resize, convert.